# I creat a query that hold some info from firebase

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I creat a query that hold some info from firebase And I got this error
[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IbM7.jpg)
And this is my query [query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odvgw.jpg)

[thi is the body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xL4E.jpg)
When i run my code the first if statement appears in the screen, which is the error I had

I tried to delete the where condition for the status but i had the same error

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is very simple, from your images I couldn't see anything but I think I know what is going on.

how firebase work is that when you use `where()` to query a collection it works fine but if you use 2 or more `where()` the firebase will take longer so to improve that they allow indexing and the error you got it should have a long URL in it click it and it will take you to your firebase project and create the needed indexes for you.
wait for like 5 min for them to build and retry using that query from your app

**PS: some time the indexing is required even with just 1 `where()`**